# Flask-admin : flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla - ModelView - form_columns

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

first of all, I'm not python proof.

I'm not sure to really understand the following sentence about the `ModelView` in the doc (http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/) :

> Class inherits configuration options from BaseModelView and they’re
>   not displayed here

As far I understand, a class which inherit from `ModelView` should inherits configurations options from `BaseModelView`

`BaseModelView` has a `form_columns` method. Then I don't understand why I got the following error `ValueError: Invalid model property name <class 'app.models.Idcard'>.n` with the following code:

models.py

```
class Idcard(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s' % unicode(self.name)
```

views.py

```
class IdcardView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ('name')

admin.add_view(IdcardView(Idcard, db.session)
```

As far I understand the error, the problem comes from the `name` in `form_columns = ('name')` butthis is clearly a parameter of my model Class `Idcard`.

If somebody has an idea ..... !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form_columns` property receive a tuple. A tuple with one item need a comma: `('name',)`.

Without the comma, it is just a string and flask-admin failed iterating each char (the first one is a `n`).

So, just change:

```
class IdcardView(ModelView):
    -form_columns = ('name')
    +form_columns = ('name',)
```

Comment: UNDERSTOOD and thanks a lots for your so quick answer. I should have found this because of the 'n' at the end of the error ! By the way it solved another issue with `nullable=False`in my model definition. I'll do another Post to explain that.